# Improve Responsiveness of ccTouchesBegan

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

At the moment, I have a puzzle game, with some objects that are movable using the ccTouchesBegan && ccTouchesMoved method

Called in ccTouchesBegan:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(newBoundingBox, touchLocation))
    {
        //Set the selectedSprite to the sprite with newBoundingBox
    }
```

Then in ccTouchesMoved i do:

```
CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);
newPos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
selectedSprite.position = newPos;
```

Now this all works fine and dandy, HOWEVER, some of the objects that I am moving are about 140x40px (on the 320x480 iPhone), and sometimes the ccTouchesBegan method won't acknowledge the boundingBox containing the touchLocation.

My question is, Can I increase the size of the boundingBox of the object so that if the user "misses" with there touch a little bit, it will help them out? It's a little frustrating requiring you to be so precise on a touch screen to move an obstacle.

EDIT: for iPhonic:

How I get touchLocation, this is in ccTouchesBegan:

```
NSSet *touchSet = [event allTouches];
int numberOfTouches = [touchSet count];
CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:[touches anyObject]];
```

allTouches is passed automatically when the a touch begins.

Comment: Oh, the smallest sprite is 98x28px, 28px is too narrow to move with a finger consistently

Comment: I am bit curios to know how you are getting the touchLocation ? Can you put the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

    for (CCSprite *tempSprite in sprites )
    {
                //Increase the size of bounding box..
        CGRect rect=tempSprite.boundingBox;
                rect.size.height=rect.size.height + 20;
                rect.size.width=rect.size.width + 20;
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location))
        {
                   //Your stuffs
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, newBoundingBox is manually set to the position + x & y units around the centre point, to counteract that problem.

Comment: Can i just increase the x & y, outside of the image, so that if they miss the image a little bit it will still catch it? will this have other implications with multiple movable Sprites on screen with "overflowing" boundingBoxes?